# Add google firebase as a library

Tags: android, ant, firebase

For some reason I do not use Android Studio, I compile my apps using a remote server with apache ant so, Is there a way to add firebase analytics, messaging... as libraries?

Comment: https://github.com/dandar3/android-google-firebase-common

Answer (score 2):

Firebase is a set of aar (Android Archive) files. Android Studio gradle plugin will simplify the use of the aar files but you can manually configure the app to use the aars. To do so in addition to linking to the libraries you will need to manually merge the manifest from all aar files to your app manifest. That includes permissions, services, receivers, content providers etc. aar is simple zip file. You can open it with unzip (or any other tool that reads zip files) and see the AndroidManifest.xml. You will also need to merge all the resources (if any) for the aar files. The last step will be to add the google_app_id from the generated google-services.json file as string resource. All in all, this is not a trivial work but it is possible.